# Using object in a method, Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm not sure what is wrong here, new to programming. I'm trying to access the `hero1` object in the `Combat` class, currently within the while loop it states that *hero1 cannot be resolved to a variable*.

I really want to know if there is any way to access the object hero1 within Combat class and it's method combat.

Just a quick note, I have a goblin class and that is working fine, it's only a problem because I've created the object in a different class from what I can tell.

Thanks and apologies for the cliche RPG references.

`Hero` class:

```
public class Hero {
    String heroname;
    double herohealth;
    int heroattack;

    String namehero() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Name of your Hero: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.heroname = scan.nextLine();

        return heroname;
    }
}
```

`Intro` class:

```
public class Intro {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hero hero1 = new Hero();
        hero1.heroattack = 15;
        hero1.herohealth = 100;

        hero1.namehero();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + hero1.heroname + "!!!");

        Combat fight = new Combat();
        fight.combat();
    }
}
```

`Combat` class:

```
public class Combat {
    public void combat() {
        Goblin goblin1 = new Goblin();

        while (hero1.herohealth > 0 || goblin1.goblinhealth > 0) {
            System.out.println(hero1.heroname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of basic issues within your posted code that are too involved to explain in SO.  I think you may want to back up and learn about Java programming some more and learn the concepts of object-oriented programming. This code most likely will not even compile.

Comment: In particular, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html would be one page to read carefully.

Comment: You should do a tuto about Java. There is many good one. And just a little thing, if you using Eclispe just do Ctrl+Alt+F to have a clear code before put it on SO.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, this is just a small section of a sprawling mess I made one night when I stayed up far too late jumping the gun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passion serenades me.  While you are making progress with tutorials as the others suggest, keep a close look out for constructors.

As an exercise, you  might want to make a "Battle" its own class.
And in the Battle's constructor, send in a `Goblin` and your `Hero` classes as arguments.

Then, you might have a method/function called `fight()`

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
hero.nameHero();

Goblin goblin1 = new Goblin();

Battle firstBattle = new Battle(hero, goblin1);
firstBattle.fight();
```

Consider that another step (not necessarily the best one) in your quest (excuse the rpg reference ;)) to becoming a great programmer